# How do I get Critical hits in Fruit Ninja? And what are they?

Tags: fruit-ninja

I occasionally slice fruits that give me 10 extra? points for a "Critical" hit.

1. Are they worth 10 points total, or 10 extra points on top of whatever you would get?
2. What impact do Critical hits have on Combos? (eg: Do they count as a combo? Is it possible to get a critical hit *and* a combo?)
3. How do I get them? Is there a specific part of the fruit I should be aiming for, or a specific motion, or perhaps a specific point in their trajectory? Or are they just completely random?

Answer (score 19):

Well,

1. They are worth 10 points instead of the traditional 1 point for standard fruit.
2. They are perfectly valid in combos like other fruit, the combo points are not multiplied by 10, you just get 9 extra points than if there was no critical hit in the combo.
3. Completely and utterly random. There is no special swiping motion or timing that will get you a critical hit. The game is known to give completely random points as seen in the Arcade mode with the random assortment of power-up bananas.

I imagine they exist for flare. It adds a random element of reward to the game to give it a little bit of extra addiction.

Comment: If you critical a bomb it won't end your game!

Comment: @DavidYell Nice, didn't know that.

Comment: The other answers were Criticised for source info. What is yours? Many other sites I have seen contradict your notion that critical hits are random. To me it seems like a waist to randomly give critical hits. Especially in Zen Games, etc. where points rely on getting criticals and combos.

Comment: The Laser Blade will give you a critical hit every time you slice a fruit that's near a bomb.  (You can see the fruit glow when they're close enough.)

Comment: The Shiny Red blade gives 25 points per Critical instead of 10.

Answer (score 2):

While [another answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/41279/274742) is fantastic, some things have changed over the years, and there are now [different types of critical hits](https://fruitninja.fandom.com/wiki/Critical#:%7E:text=In%20Fruit%20Ninja%2C%20a%20critical%20can%20be%20scored,points%2C%20unless%20the%20Shiny%20Red%20blade%20is%20equipped.).

With the standard critical hit being well outlined above, the others are:

### Critical +25

> These criticals appear when the Shiny Red Blade is used, and are worth twenty-five points each. When sliced, the quote appears with the red "+25" over the "+10".

### Laser Critical

> These criticals appear in the Cherry Bomb Mini Game and when the Laser Blade is used. When the fruits are near the bombs, they will generate a shrouding electric arc on their outside. Quickly slice and make sure not to slice the bomb by mistake.

---

***NOTE:** Critical hits can be achieved in all modes except Zen.*

<sub>Quotes pulled from the [Fruit Ninja fandom](https://fruitninja.fandom.com/wiki/Fruit_Ninja_Wiki).</sub>

Answer (score -3):

1. You receive 10 extra points, so you receive 11 points*.
2. You can get a combo and a critical hit in the same hit.
3. It's when you cut the fruit perfectly in the middle of the fruit, it's hard, but it happens.

*At the start of Classic mode, there's 6 fruit and then a bomb. If you do not get a critical on any of these, you will have 6 points while waiting for the bomb. If you *do* get a critical, you will have 16 points.

Comment: Do you have any source for this informations? Two of the three points contradict with the highest voted answer.

Comment: It is totally and utterly random. As stated in the comments of that answer by Alex. You receive 10 points instead of 11. Do you even play this game? The first point you have there is easily observable!

Answer (score -5):

A critical hit isn't random: it's when you hit a fruit perfectly down its middle. Now you might say that's hard but don't sweat it: it happens anyways.

Comment: How did you find that information? Or is it a random guess?

Comment: I can get critical even when only stroking the tip of a banana with my finger.

Comment: @QAdley Are you sure there isn't a latency issue that's making you think you only got the tip?

Comment: Utterly wrong. I'd give you points for imagination, but that's not what this site is about.