# How often do criticals happen in Fruit Ninja?

Tags: fruit-ninja

I know that criticals are random occurrences that give an additional ten points, and I know how to get them.

However, what are the odds of getting the additional 10 points? How often do criticals happen in Fruit Ninja?

Comment: Welcome to the arcade! [This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41270/how-do-i-get-critical-hits-in-fruit-ninja-and-what-are-they) should shed some light on the subject.

Answer (score 3):

All we know is that it is random. Unfortunately, there are a lot of ways a game developer could program in random, some of which could rely on elements in the same environment that would drastically differ from player to player. As a result, we can only really approximate the chances, and we can only really do so by playing the game and working out how frequently they come up.

At present, it appears the critical chance rate on Android rests at about 2-3%

---

## Android

I installed the game on my Android phone, and played ten matches. Here are my results:

| Round | Final Score | Critical Cuts | Rough Score at Critical Cut |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 50 | 1 | 45 |
| 3 | 60 | 1 | 50 |
| 4 | 140 | 2 | 73, 105 |
| 5 | 126 | 3 | 29, 59, 109 |
| 6 | 119 | 2 | 36 |
| 7 | 147 | 4 | 39, 56, 126, 146 |
| 8 | 28 | 0 |  |
| 9 | 141 | 3 | 18, 54, 125 |
| 10 | 83 | 1 | 27 |

Based off these rough numbers, we can see I get a critical between roughly every 30<sup>th</sup> and 50<sup>th</sup> cut. That equates to between 3.33% and 2%, with an average of roughly 2.5%.

As I have time, I will do more tests. If the numbers change in larger quantity, I will let you know; it is also entirely possible that the random number generator in my version of the game will give me better or poorer odds based off environmental changes that can not easily be replicated by other players; and not for any particular reason, either. Simply because that is how random number generators work in video games.